# Does any one implemented Android Junit Test for testing a background service?

Tags: android, junit

I have been trying to create a juint test for testing a background service which i started in MainActivity class. Is there a way to test the service.

Comment: I assume you could check if the service was started correctly, unit test the methods of your service and check whether other methods were called after successfully starting the service. Oh and you should test whether your service terminates cleanly when you stop it. o go into more detail i suggest you edit your question with some more detail what your service is doing and how you start/stop/monitor it

Answer (score 2):

You may use a [ServiceTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html), see http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/service_testing.html